# How to get Array as input in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, dom

I'm trying to get array as input from DOM in react

I tried to do it like this

`const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);`

`<input value={arr} onChange={(e) => setArr(e.target.value)} />`

How can I actually get array input in react

Comment: `e.target.value` is only 1 value. Why do you want an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to give array as input, in which all values are separated by ",", example: `A,B,C` should setArr as ["A","B","C"] you can do it like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    const arrValue = inputValue.split(',');
    setArr(arrValue);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleInputChange} />
      <p>{arr}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example **handleInputChange** captures the value of the input using **e.target.value** and  then **.split(',')** method converts it into an array by comma separator.

If you want the input to be split not by a comma, but by something else, such as a space, simply change the character in **.split()**.